# Azure App Gateway Session Affinity - Third-party Cookie

Tags: azure-application-gateway

We're using Azure App Gateway as our load balancer and need session affinity (so that requests for a particular user are all routed to the same backend node). Azure App Gateway uses a cookie to achieve the session affinity. The challenge is that our javascript is embedded in other company's websites. Because of this it's considered a third-party cookie.

Chrome is going to start blocking these in Q3 2024: https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd/prepare/prepare-for-phaseout

When we load a website and view the cookie we see this warning:
[image]

Is there a way in Azure App Gateway that the session affinity cookie can be marked as partioned (CHIPS) - https://developers.google.com/privacy-sandbox/3pcd/chips. Or any other way to workaround this challenge?

Comment: there is no built-in functionality in Azure Application Gateway to mark the session affinity cookie as partitioned (CHIPS). One workaround could be to use a custom cookie name for session affinity and configure the backend servers to handle it accordingly. This way, the cookie would not be considered a third-party cookie since it would be specific to the domain of the backend servers.

Comment: checkout:

-   [Enable Cookie based affinity with an Application Gateway](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/ingress-controller-cookie-affinity#enable-cookie-based-affinity-with-an-application-gateway)
-   [Application Gateway HTTP settings configuration - Cookie-based affinity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-http-settings#cookie-based-affinity)

Comment: -   [Troubleshoot Azure Application Gateway session affinity issues - Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/how-to-troubleshoot-application-gateway-session-affinity-issues#troubleshoot-azure-application-gateway-session-affinity-issues)
-   [Troubleshoot Azure Application Gateway session affinity issues - Possible problem causes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/how-to-troubleshoot-application-gateway-session-affinity-issues#possible-problem-causes)